# Displaying columns in correct order on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a page using Issuu, where I can embed each publication in it's relevant order, on a desktop this looks great and all of the publications are listed in the correct order (oldest at the bottom etc), the test html code I'm using is:

```
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <!--Issue 06-->
        <div>Issue 06<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 06" /></div>
        <!--Issue 03-->
        <div>Issue 03<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 03" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <!--Issue 05-->
        <div>Issue 05<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 05" /></div>
        <!--Issue 02-->
        <div>Issue 02<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 02" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <!--Issue 04-->
        <div>Issue 04<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 04" /></div>
        <!--Issue 01-->
        <div>Issue 01<img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 01" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, when viewing this on a mobile devices, it's loading the columns in their correct order which is throwing out the order of the magazine issues. I understand why it's doing this, but I can't think of a good workaround for it to work both on desktop (as it currently is) and on mobile devices.

I've created a fiddle on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vhbzs/

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, two rows with only three issues per row:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <!--Issue 06-->
        <div>Issue 06
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 06" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <!--Issue 05-->
        <div>Issue 05
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 05" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <!--Issue 04-->
        <div>Issue 04
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 04" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <!--Issue 03-->
        <div>Issue 03
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 03" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <!--Issue 02-->
        <div>Issue 02
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 02" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 column">
        <!--Issue 01-->
        <div>Issue 01
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250&text=Issue 01" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vhbzs/3/)

Comment: Works perfectly for me, thanks very much. I've just understood the bootstrap grid better with your solution! Thanks again.